# Regex match anything but a fixed chars count of a string?

Tags: java, regex

Can I define a `regexpr` where anything is matched, but an offset is applied to the end of the string?

Example:
`abcdefg` with an offset of `3` would only match `abcd`.

I need this for a `matcher.group(0).replaceAll(".", "X")` to mask out any character of a string, but omitting a fixed length at the end.

Comment: I don't understand the example. Why *regex* and not substring?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could perhaps use something like this?

```
^.+(?=...$)
```

That will ensure there's still 3 chars left until the end of the string.

Or maybe using substrings?

```
String Str = new String("abcdefg");
if (Str.length() > 3) {
    System.out.println(Str.substring(0, Str.length()-3));
}
```